# check the value of multiple radio buttons in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue in selection of radio button by default.

following is my json data

```
var Result = [{
    "Questions": [{
        "Question": "question1",
        "Answer": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "Question": "question2",
        "Answer": "No"
    },
    {
        "Question": "question3",
        "Answer": null
    }]
},
{
    "Questions": [{
        "Question": "question1",
        "Answer": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "Question": "question3",
        "Answer": "No",
    },
    {
        "Question": "question4",
        "Answer": null,
    }]
}];
```

With this json data, I need to select the radio button based on answer.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Result">
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="question in item.Questions">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
        <div>{{question.Question}}</div>
        <div>
            <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 no-padding"><input type="radio" ng-model="question.Answer"  name="questions_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-checked='question.Answer == "Yes"' /> <span>Yes</span></span>
            <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 no-padding"><input type="radio" ng-model="question.Answer" name="questions_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}" ng-checked='question.Answer == "No"' /> <span>No</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am not able to do that. Can anyone let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: I think you have problem with your input data. check the JSON. Alter that for your need.

Comment: how it should be if it has to work?

Comment: can you make clear how the output should be. so that I may help

Comment: also, you are iterating incorrectly. there is no `{{question.Question}}`. the actual question is inside. `{{question.Questions.Question}}`

Comment: I have changed the json and html code, will that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Do not use [`ngChecked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) together with [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), from the docs:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as
>   this can lead to unexpected behavior.

2) You don't have value attribute on your inputs. You can add `value="Yes"/value="No"` attributes to corresponding inputs and use them together with [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

**UPDATE:** Working code snipped added:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainController', function mainController($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.$index = 1;
  $scope.Questions = [{
        "Question": "question1",
        "Answer": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "Question": "question2",
        "Answer": "No"
    },
    {
        "Question": "question3",
        "Answer": null
    }];
    
});
```

```html
<!-- JS -->
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
     <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="question in Questions">
          <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
              <div>{{question.Question}}</div>
              <div>
                  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 no-padding"><input type="radio" ng-model="question.Answer"  name="questions_{{$parent.$index + '_' + $index}}" value="Yes" /> <span>Yes</span></span>
                  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 no-padding"><input type="radio" ng-model="question.Answer" name="questions_{{$parent.$index + '_' + $index}}" value="No" /> <span>No</span></span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't worked. When I loop the json, the last question answer will be checked. remaining other questions wont checked

Comment: I think the problem could be then with name attribute.

Comment: @user1268130 can you use `name="questions_{{$parent.$index + '_' + $index}}"` instead of `questions_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}`?

Comment: could you help me with that, I was breaking my head since 2hours

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating incorrectly, Check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/3wgJWFQCckBGNRRYzyjA?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Questions = [{
    "Questions": [{
      "Question": "question1",
      "Answer": "Yes"
    }, {
      "Question": "question2",
      "Answer": "No"
    }, {
      "Question": "question3",
      "Answer": null
    }]
  }, {
    "Questions": [{
      "Question": "question1",
      "Answer": "Yes"
    }, {
      "Question": "question3",
      "Answer": "No",
    }, {
      "Question": "question4",
      "Answer": null,
    }]
  }]
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="question in Questions">
    Set-{{$index+1}}
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="data in question.Questions">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data.Answer" value="Yes"> Yes
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data.Answer" value="No"> No
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data.Answer" value=null> Null
      </label>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Don't use `ng-model` and `ng-checked`. use `value` or `ng-value`instead of `ng-checked`.

Check this.

Comment: I removed the name attribute, then it worked fine. thanks